# Access class function inside lambda which is executed in an instance

Tags: c++, lambda

**Context**

In a header-file `matrix.h` I defined a struct holding a matrix.
A special feature is a function inside this struct which allows for iterating over the rows and columns and apply a function to each iteration step. The idea is to not have to write that loop a thousand times.

```cpp
template <class T>
struct Matrix{
    T* matrix;
    int columns, rows;

    Matrix(int rows, int columns) : rows(rows), columns(columns)
        matrix = new T[columns * rows];
    }

    template<typename Func>
    void iterate_over_matrix(Func function) {

        for (std::size_t row = 0; row < rows; ++row) {
            for (std::size_t column = 0; column < columns; ++column) {
                function(row, column);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Using this works without any problem, e.g.:

```cpp
/*Initialize the matrix with the numbers 0..N for type T*/
template <class T>
void Matrix<T>::init_dummy_matrix(){

    iterate_over_matrix(
        [this](std::size_t& row, std::size_t& col) {
            set_element<T>(
                row, col,
                col + columns * row // Same result as having a counter -> 0..N
            );
        }
    );
}
```

**Problem**

I want to reuse this functionality on instances of the matrix-class. E.g. while calculating the *outer_product* in a class `LinearAlgebra`:

```cpp
/*Set the element at position [row] and [col]umn with given [val]ue.*/
template <class T>
void Matrix<T>::set_element(const int &row, const int &col, T val) {
    matrix[col + columns * row] = val;
}


/** Calculate the outer product [vector_1]T * [vector_2]. */
template <class T>
Matrix<T> LinAlg::outer_product(
        const std::vector<T> &vector_1
        , const std::vector<T> &vector_2
    ) {

        Matrix matrix = Matrix<T>(
            vector_1.size()
            , vector_2.size()
        );

        matrix.iterate_over_matrix(
            [this, &vector_1, &vector_2](std::size_t& row, std::size_t& col) {
                set_element<T>(
                    row, col,
                    vector_1[row] * vector_2[col]
                );
            }
        );

        return matrix;
}
```

Anyhow, this fails with `'set_element': identifier not found`.

**Question**

While the error-message is pretty clear in stating the problem, I have no clue how to come around this - Especially since passing the context via `this` does not help...

***How can I access a class-function inside a lambda which is called on an instance of that object?***

Comment: `this` is actually an instance of `LinAlg` and not `Matrix<T>`.. so you need to pass in `matrix` by reference or pointer, and call `matrix::set_element` on that instance.

Comment: This is how I would do it (capture matrix instead of this): https://onlinegdb.com/A72vMO3wt

Comment: Thanks for your fast answers! This works and is executable :) Anyhow, I'm a little confused that it is possible to reference the matrix-instance to a function inside this instance and not get any weird error-messages - I think I have to read some additional articles about scoping ^^